# Low voltage transformer on both doorbell & furnace

Tags: electrical

I have ring video doorbell constantly have to be recharged I am thinking it's because my low voltage transformer. my transformer currently has the doorbell wire to it and the furnace both. Which I found at the light fixture in the bedroom Above the light. I am wondering if I am supposed to have 2 separate Transformers or if I can run 2 separate Transformers to give myself more juice to help the ring video doorbell to keep   It charged?

Comment: What's the transfer rated at (Voltage, VA)?    It's not common to share a transformer between a doorbell and a furnace. If it were me, I'd get a new transformer for the doorbell, and stop using the furnace transformer to power the doorbell.

Comment: I agree with tester is is unusual to have a transformer powering the furnace and the doorbell but I have seen it before. Could you measure the voltage this would give a clue if the transformer is the correct voltage. For example it could be 12v when the ring needs 17-24 if memory serves.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you've overloaded a 40 VA transformer.

I think what's happened is the Ring is designed to power itself by leaking a small amount of current through the doorbell ringer (but not enough for the ringer to actually ring).  Similar to how old-school dimmers leak current through the incandescent bulb.  **However in your case, your ringer is too small/high-impedance, and it can't leak enough power to stay alive**.

The answer is put something in parallel with the doorbell ringer so current can leak around it.

You could try fitting a Lutron LUT-MLC device there (in parallel with the doorbell ringer) and see if that clears the problem.  The LUT-MLC allows additional leakage to make inline-powered devices happy.

Comment: Where did you come up with 40va for the transformer?

Comment: @EdBeal standard thermostat transformer.  If it's not one it could easily be changed to one.

Comment: Many are only 20VA there is no real standard not even the voltage is standard but most are 17-24v